# Http Sessions life cycle in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a task to show to the site admin a list of user names and how many tomcat sessions are currently utilized by each user (along with some other support-related information).

I keep authenticated users as the application context attribute as follows (sparing unnecessary details).

```
Hashtable<String, UserInfo> logins //maps login to UserInfo
```

where UserInfo is defined as

```
class UserInfo implements Serializable {
String login;
private transient Map<HttpSession, String> sessions = 
      Collections.synchronizedMap(
             new WeakHashMap<HttpSession, String>() //maps session to sessionId
      );
...
}
```

Each successful login stores the session into this `sessions` map.
My `HttpSessionsListener` implementation in `sessionDestroyed()` removes the destroyed session from this map and, if sessions.size() == 0, removes UserInfo from `logins`.

From time to time I have 0 sessions showing up for some users. Peer reviews and unit testing show that the code is correct. All sessions are serializable.

Is it possible that Tomcat offloads sessions from memory to the hard drive, e.g. when there is a period of inactivity (session timeout is set to 40 minutes)? Are there any other scenarios where sessions are 'lost' from GC point of view, but HttpSessionsListener.sessionDestroyed() wasn't invoked?

J2SE 6, Tomcat 6 or 7 standalone, behaviour is consistent on any OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you find that you get the issue following a restart of Tomcat?  Tomcat will serialize active sessions to disk during a successful shutdown and then deserialize on startup - I'm not sure whether this will result in a call to your HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated() as the session isn't strictly created, just deserialized (this may be not be correct(!), but can be tested fairly easily).

Have you also compared your results with the Tomcat managers session stats?  It keeps track of the number of active sessions, and should tie up with your figures, if not, you know your code is wrong.

Also, probably unrelated to your issue, but is there a good reason why you are using Hashtable and WeakHashMap?  I tend to go with ConcurrentHashMap if i need a thread safe Map implementation, its performance is much better.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is a good idea. There is no good reason, just some legacy considerations, that should not be relevant anymore. I don't think there was a restart of the server involved, but I will double check - my sessions are transient after all. In any case I have to resolve the issue, and if you are right, I will mark you answer.

Comment: What makes you think that you're HttpSession's are transient?  The transient modifier on the sessions Map seems redundant as the UserInfo class does not implement Serializable (is this where the confusion lies?).  And come to think of it HttpSession as the key to a map isn't quite right as its an Interface, and so the equals() and hashcode() are dependant on Tomcat (or other app server) chosen implementation.  You would be better having the swapping the key to be the session id and value to be the HttpSession.

Comment: UserInfo implements Serializable, since this web app works in HA cluster and also "survives" reboots without dropping the sessions (which requires serialization of application context attributes as well). It was my mistake to omit it in the code example.

Comment: HttpSession as a key for WeakHashMap is not right, I know. The idea here was to eliminate potential memory leak by not holding strong references to sessions. Were I holding them, every missed `sessionDestroyed()` call on Tomcat side would create a memory leak. By using weak references I ensure it doesn't happen, and WeakHashMap requires weak ref'd object as a key for this to work. I would prefer something like ConcurrentHashSet containing weak wrappers around sessions, but it makes it quite complicated for such a simple functionality.

Comment: At the end of the day my approach is not correct. Transient sessions map makes full recovery after server restart impossible, but serialization is not an option also. I was not able to identify why all sessions disappear from weak references with no SessionListener calls, however there are too many assumptions about the web container that make this code unfit for production. I did prove that SessionListener is not getting called during de-serialization (shouldn't, also). And sessions silently disappear without restarts. I will mark you answer as correct, for all the right pointers.

Answer (score 5):

As this question got close to 5k views, I think it would be beneficial to provide an example of a working solution.

The approach outlined in the question is wrong - it will not handle server restarts and will not scale. Here is a better approach.

First, your HttpServlet needs to handle user logins and logouts, something along these lines:

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
              throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = req.getParameter("do"); 
        HttpSession session =  req.getSession(true);
        //simple plug. Use your own controller here.
        switch (action) {
            case "logout":
                session.removeAttribute("user");
                break;
            case "login":
                User u = new User(session.getId(), req.getParameter("login"));
                //store user on the session
                session.setAttribute("user",u);                    
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The User bean has to be Serializable and has to re-register itself upon de-serialization:

```
class User implements Serializable {

    private String sessionId;
    private String login;

    User(String sessionId, String login) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getLogin() { return login; }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        //re-register this user in sessions 
        UserAttributeListener.sessions.put(sessionId,this); 
    }

}
```

You will also need an HttpAttributeListener to handle session lifecycle properly:

```
public class UserAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    static Map<String, User> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if ("user".equals(event.getName()))
             sessions.put(event.getSession().getId(), (User) event.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if ("user".equals(event.getName()))
            ExampleServlet.sessions.remove(event.getSession().getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        if ("user".equals(event.getName()))
            ExampleServlet.sessions.put(event.getSession().getId(),
                      (User)event.getValue());
    }
}
```

Of course, you will need to register your listener in web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.servlet.UserAttributeListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

After that, you can always access the static map in UserAttributeListener to get an idea of how many sessions are running, how many sessions each user is using etc. Ideally, you would have a bit more complex data structure warranting its own separate singleton class with proper access methods. Using containers with copy-on-write concurrent strategy might also be a good idea, depending on the use case.

Comment: Thanks for this, but could you explain under what circumstances, and by what process is `User.readObject()` called?

Comment: @Framcis: if you restart your Tomcat and have web.xml marked with <distributable/>, Tomcat (or other web container) will serialize your session attributes, restart, then read it from hard drive. This is where you need de-serializer to re-register User in global map.

Answer (score 3):

When a client visits the webapp for the first time and/or the HttpSession is obtained for the first time via `request.getSession()`, the servlet container creates a new `HttpSession` object, generates a long and unique ID (which you can get by `session.getId()`), and store it in the server's memory. The servlet container also sets a Cookie in the Set-Cookie header of the HTTP response with JSESSIONID as its name and the unique session ID as its value.

As per the `HTTP cookie` specification (a contract a decent web browser and web server have to adhere to), the client (the web browser) is required to send this cookie back in subsequent requests in the Cookie header for as long as the cookie is valid (i.e. the unique ID must refer to an unexpired session and the domain and path are correct). Using your browser's built-in HTTP traffic monitor, you can verify that the cookie is valid (press F12 in Chrome / Firefox 23+ / IE9+, and check the Net/Network tab). The servlet container will check the Cookie header of every incoming `HTTP` request for the presence of the cookie with the name `JSESSIONID` and use its value (the session ID) to get the associated `HttpSession` from server's memory.

The `HttpSession` stays alive until it has not been used for more than the timeout value specified in `<session-timeout>`, a setting in `web.xml`. The timeout value defaults to 30 minutes. So, when the client doesn't visit the web app for longer than the time specified, the servlet container trashes the session. Every subsequent request, even with the cookie specified, will not have access to the same session anymore; the servlet container will create a new session.

On the client side, the session cookie stays alive for as long as the browser instance is running. So, if the client closes the browser instance (all tabs/windows), then the session is trashed on the client's side. In a new browser instance, the cookie associated with the session wouldn't exist, so it would no longer be sent. This causes an entirely new HTTPSession to be created, with an entirely new session cookie begin used.

Comment: Your answer has all the right facts, describes session lifecycle in the web container and I am sure it will help someone. But I am not sure I see how it helps to return a "list of user names and how many tomcat sessions are currently utilized by each user" - main reason for the question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing something from scratch, check out psi-probe.

http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/

This may just be a simple drop in that solves your problems.

Comment: Awesome tool, thanks. Will definitely come handy. Unfortunately, the feature I need is to show logged in users with current number of sessions and what clients are they using/what state they are in to speed up support calls.

Comment: Hmm.  Just looked at your code, not clear from what is posted what the issue is.. can you post a more complete example?